# Why does rm inside a function not delete objects?

Tags: r

```
rel.mem <- function(nm) {
  rm(nm)
}
```

I defined the above function rel.mem -- takes a single argument and passes it to rm

```
> ls()
[1] "rel.mem"
> x<-1:10
> ls()
[1] "rel.mem" "x"      
> rel.mem(x)
> ls()
[1] "rel.mem" "x"
```

Now you can see what I call rel.mem x is not deleted -- I know this is due to the incorrect environment on which rm is being attempted.

What is a good fix for this?

**Criteria for a good fix:**

1. The caller should not have to pass the environment
2. The callee (rel.mem) should be able to determine the environment by using an R language facility (call stack inspection, aspects, etc.)
3. The interface of the function rel.mem should be kept simple -- idiot proof: call rel.mem -- then rel.mem takes it from there -- no need to pass environments.

NOTES:

1. As many commenters have pointed out that one easy fix is to pass the environment.
2. What I meant by a good fix [and I should have clarified it] is that the callee function (in this case rel.mem) is able to calculate/find out the environment when the caller was referring to and then remove the object from the right environment.
3. The type of reasoning in "2" can be done in other languages by inspecting the call stack -- for example in Java I would throw a dummy exception -- catch it and then parse the call stack. In other languages still I could use Aspect Oriented techniques. The question is can something like that be done in R?
4. As one commenter has suggested that there may be multiple objects with the same name and thus the "right" environment is meaningless -- as I've stated above that in other languages it is possible (sometimes with some creative trickery) to interpret the call-stack -- this may not be possible in R
5. As one commenter has suggested that rm(list=nm, envir = parent.frame()) will remove this from the parent environment. This is correct -- however I'm looking for something that will work for an arbitrary call depth.

Comment: Also, please *don't* post commands like `rm(list = ls())` in your question unless they are critical to the understanding of your question - you don't want anyone running them accidentally.

Comment: @Gregor -- actually I should have specified -- my question was -- is there a way to do it without explicitly passing the environment each time?

Comment: @Gregor -- please see the updated question ... thanks.

Comment: @DirtySockSniffer -- hi, I've updated the question -- hope that helps -- thanks

Comment: The question is insufficiently specified. There can be be more than one object with the same name in different environments. How is the "right environmnent" defined?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi: If the questioner wants the "right answer" to be removal of the first instance of the named object found up the current search path (as of the invocation of the function) then I think that using `apropos()` to determine the "target" for removal might succeed.

Comment: @42 ... as I said -- that in other languages I can interpret the call stack to find the right object -- this might not be possible in R -- I'll update the question with you comment

Comment: You may not understand the R correlates of the "call stack". The interpreter will be searching through a series of frames populated with data objects and functions created by nested function calls.

Answer (score 15):

The quick answer is that you're in a different environment - essentially picture the variables in a box: you have a box for the function and one for the Global Environment. You just need to tell `rm` where to find that box.

So

```
rel_mem <- function(nm) {
   # State the environment
   rm(list=nm, envir = .GlobalEnv )
}
x = 10
rel_mem("x")
```

Alternatively, you can use the `pos` argument, e.g.

```
rel_mem <- function(nm) {
   rm(list=nm, pos=1 )
}
```

If you type `search()` you will see a vector of environments, the global is number `1`.

Another two options are

- `envir = parent.frame()` if you want to go one level up the call stack
- Use `inherits = TRUE` to go up the call stack until you find something

---

In the above code, notice that I'm passing the object as a character - I'm passing the `"x"` not `x`. We can be clever and avoid this using the `substitute` function

```
rel_mem <- function(nm) {
   rm(list = as.character(substitute(nm)), envir = .GlobalEnv )
}
```

To finish I'll just add that deleting things in the `.GlobalEnv` from a function is generally a **bad** idea.

Further resources:

- Environments:http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html
- Substitute function: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#capturing-expressions

Comment: many thanks for the answer -- I've updated the question -- would appreciate any input. Thanks.

Comment: @BenBolker you are correct -- I'm looking for an arbitrary ancestor locator mechanism

Answer (score 1):

If you are using another function to find the global objects within your function such as `ls()`, you must state the environment in it explicitly too:

```
rel_mem <- function(nm) {
   # State the environment in both functions
   rm(list = ls(envir = .GlobalEnv) %>% .[startsWith(., "plot_")], envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```